# When pass props from function getStaticProps to a component and console.log it returns undefined

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs, next.js

I am working with nextjs and I pass props to component and after console.log it and it returns undefined. Why?

Here is my code:

```
import axios from "axios"

function HomePage ({data})  {
  console.log(data)
  return (
      <div>Home</div>
) 

  }

       export default HomePage
       export const getStaticProps = async () => {
          const res = await axios.get("http://localhost:3000/api/books");
          const data = await res.data.books
  
           return {
           props: {
               data
              }
          }
          
          
      }
  getStaticProps()
```

I expect to get an array of object but instead  get an undefined

Comment: What do you see when you check the Network tab of the Developer console? What is the response for that particular request?

Comment: Here is a response:  https://www.dropbox.com/s/cvc97arl17a1lp9/chrome_VIsoQP3cE7.png?dl=0

Comment: It would seem that your original request is getting redirected (304 as the response code), and looking at the XHR list on the left, I can see another request to the `books` endpoint. What do you get from that second XHR `books`? To be more specific, what's inside the [`Response` tab](https://i.imgur.com/mKoF4EV.png)?

Comment: Inside response tab is JSON: https://www.dropbox.com/s/9cgg2lbagalsc69/chrome_ZjGrE0vNUG.png?dl=0